# Youtube iOS app rejected with 18.1

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube

My iOS Youtube app was rejected based solely on section 18.1 (sexual content etc...) They sent me a screenshot with the search term ([s] [e] [x]) and the standard youtube videos displayed. My app is not just a youtube player it is targeted at a specific market and technically / UI features are all good.

Question is - Has anyone experienced this before? How can the other Youtube apps and also the standard Youtube player be accepted when the same search term returns the exact same results as my player... I am using the standard Obj-C / Youtube API's...

Comment: What age rating did you give your app?

Comment: I initially had it with an innapropriate rating 6+ however had since changed that to 17+. Apple has since written back and said they made a mistake and that it does not violate 18.1... Just wanted to see if anyone else had a similar experience